# Is it possible to delete signal

Tags: c++, c, signals

Is it possible to delete / unmap / remap a signal?
For exemple, ctrl-c actually send a SIGINT signal.
Can i modify this, so that ctrl-c keypress doesn't throw a signal but write its ascii value on stdin as any other key?

I don't know if I'm very clear, don't hesitate to ask for more informations

EDIT:

I want my terminal to stop responding to ctrl-c as a signal

Comment: Please, check [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/). The answer is yes, you can capture the signal and handle it to do something rather than its default behavior.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to stop your terminal driver from responding to Ctrl-C as an instruction to send a SIGINT to the foreground process group, or whether it is possible for a process receiving a SIGINT to do something other than terminate abnormally, or ... what?

Comment: Yes, I don't want my terminal driver to respond to ctrl-c as a signal, i just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a POSIX system, you can control which character sends SIGINT, or set it to no character.

```
struct termios t;
if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t) == 0) {
    t.c_cc[VINTR] = 0;  // set the INT character to 0 (disable)
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t);
} else {
    // stdin is not a terminal
}
```

See [General Terminal Interface](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html), [tcgetattr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcgetattr.html), [tcsetattr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcsetattr.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch signals inside your code and handle them as you wish.

Here is a basic example, what you need to do is to register the callback to handle the signal you want to catch. In this case, the `SIGINT`:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGINT) {
    printf("received SIGINT\n");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");
  }
  // A long long wait so that we can easily issue a signal to this process
  while(1) {
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So, in this example the `sig_handler()` function is registered to handle the `SIGINT` signal by using the `signal(SIGINT, sig_handler)` call.

More examples in [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/).

Comment: Note that within the signal handlers they're very constrained as to what operations they can perform.  Not async-signal-safe output using `printf` is one such forbidden operation.

Comment: See [`man signal-safety`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli • Thanks for the clarification, and the link!  I've tweaked my prior comment.